# How to Setup Axis Points in g3data of 16.04's apt-get?

Tags: 16.04, image-processing

I do `g3data image.png`. I start by clicking `Set point X1 on X axis (1)`. I setup axis points unsuccessfully

1. Set axis points X1 and press second click
2. Set axis points Y1 and press second click
3. Set axis points Y2 but it does not accept second-click. I cannot do anything here

   - it did not ask Y1 axis points.

[image]

Open

- Whose version of g3data is in apt-get? Ticket about it [here](https://github.com/pn2200/g3data/issues/7).
- What is the purpose of those "T"-shaped/green things?
- What is the purpose of red squares?

The first point of every axis point is green square. However, it put those two T-figures automatically in the middle of the figure.

### Problems of GUI in 13" display [secondary]

This is not the main problem here because I can reach the GUI in the bigger display. 
I cannot reach the end of the GUI

[image]

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
g3data: 5 years old version, development [here](https://github.com/jonasfrantz/g3data2), aptitude info 1:1.5.3-2.1 and 1:1.5.3-2.1; but latest version should be [here](https://github.com/pn2200/g3data) although 6 years ago according to the original developer
Related ticket: [Github](https://github.com/jonasfrantz/g3data2/issues/4) about *Some deprecations causing problems on Ubuntu 14.04*

Comment: Maybe you need axis points before you can export point data?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Please, see the body now. I sent a message to the developer to confirm the version of g3data in apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the maintainer [here](https://github.com/pn2200/g3data/issues/7#issuecomment-227317756)

> There are two methods to set up the Y axis.
>
> The first method is: Press the button labeled "Set point Y1 on Y axis", then left-click
>   (mouse button 1) on the image, then fill in the text box labeled "Y1
>   value". Then, press the button labeled "Set point Y2 on Y axis", then
>   left-click on the image, then fill in the text box labeled "Y2 value".
>
> The second method is: 
>   Right-click (mouse button 3) on the image once to set the Y1 point on
>   Y axis, then fill in the text box labeled "Y1 value". Then right-click
>   (mouse button 3) on the image once to set the Y2 point on Y axis, then
>   fill in the text box labeled "Y2 value".
>
> The green T shapes mark the control points for the Y axis. There are
>   equivalent purple T shapes to mark the control points for the X axis.
>   The red squares are the actual data points you want to collect.

- Problem: I filed a bug report about the issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/g3data/+bug/1593972).

Comment: The author's website has a link to the g3data**2** github repository, but it was last updated 5 years ago: https://github.com/jonasfrantz/g3data2

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A branch.